# Javascript autoselect for dropdown not selecting

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

I'm progamming a website and I would love to select all my dropdowns automatically instead of doing it manually.
The thing is that my JS code brings the values, but it doesn't select any option so the box keeps like "Select an option"

HTML:

```
 <tr> <td>Gender</td> <td> <div class="select2-container select2-container-active" id="s2id_ContentPlaceHolder1_personDetails_genderDropDownList"> <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="select2-choice select2-default" tabindex="-1"> <span class="select2-chosen" id="select2-chosen-2">Select an Option</span> <abbr class="select2-search-choice-close"></abbr> <span class="select2-arrow" role="presentation"> <b role="presentation"></b></span></a><label for="s2id_autogen2" class="select2-offscreen"></label> <input class="select2-focusser select2-offscreen" type="text" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" aria-labelledby="select2-chosen-2" id="s2id_autogen2" tabindex="0" autocomplete="Female"></div> <select name="_ctl0:ContentPlaceHolder1:personDetails:genderDropDownList" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_personDetails_genderDropDownList" onchange="nzis.UpdateDropdownErrorLabel(this)" errorlabel="mandatory" tabindex="-1" title="" style="display: none;"> <option selected="selected" value=""></option> <option value="M">Male</option> <option value="F">Female</option> </select> </td> </tr>
```

JavaScript:

```
var index = document.getElementById('s2id_ContentPlaceHolder1_personDetails_genderDropDownList).selectedIndex; alert("value="+document.getElementById('s2id_ContentPlaceHolder1_personDetails_genderDropDownList').value); alert("text="+document.getElementById('s2id_ContentPlaceHolder1_personDetails_genderDropDownList').options[1].text); s2id_autogen1.value= document.getElementById('s2id_ContentPlaceHolder1_personDetails_genderDropDownList').options[2].text; s2id_autogen1.checked = true; var index = document.getElementById('s2id_ContentPlaceHolder1_personDetails_genderDropDownList').selectedIndex; alert("value="+document.getElementById('s2id_ContentPlaceHolder1_personDetails_genderDropDownList').value); alert("text="+document.getElementById('s2id_ContentPlaceHolder1_personDetails_genderDropDownList').options[1].text); s2id_autogen2.value= document.getElementById('s2id_ContentPlaceHolder1_personDetails_genderDropDownList').options[2].text;
```

Any suggestion? :)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your `s2id_ContentPlaceHolder1_personDetails_genderDropDownList`(rediculously long id btw) is a `div`, not a `select`, so calling things like `.value` and `.options` etc on it, wouldn't result in anything but an error if your lucky

Comment: Thanks! But I tried with the select attribute but didn't work.

Comment: Simply changing it to a `div` still doesn't magically repair it. And if you tidy up your code a (whole) bit, you would see that your JS has errors in it either way: [https://jsfiddle.net/aj33whrd/](https://jsfiddle.net/aj33whrd/). You missed a single-quote, `s2id_autogen1` is never referenced to a DOM element, haven't checked further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't seem to have an element with id `ContentPlaceHolder1_personDetails_titleDropDownList` so it's failing to get the element using `document.getElementById` and therefore you're most likely getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'selectedIndex' of null` in your console.

**Edit**: did you mean to use `s2id_ContentPlaceHolder1_personDetails_genderDropDownList` as your selector?

Comment: Thanks a lot Sauntimo's!!

Comment: Yes, I apologize for that. I meant gender, not title. Sorry, I'm pretty tired :(

Comment: you're welcome! if this fixed your problem you could accept my answer and then people will know this is resolved :)

Comment: I would love to! But the problem persists. When I write JS code in my browser console, the dropdowns menus won't change. They keep 'Select an option'. I think I need to automate clicks in order to autoselect my dropdowns, but I don't know how to do it and everything I tried before didn't work 

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve but [here's an example](https://jsfiddle.net/sauntimo/wrhrsg84/) I just wrote of selecting an option using javascript - perhaps that will help?

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what I need. But it doesn't work in my design. I just want to add some javascript temporary bookmarklet to my page so I don't have to select those options from the dropdowns whenever I want to test changes I make.

Comment: Can you create a bookmarklet using a link with javascript in it, like so? `<a href="javascript:(function(){
var opt = document.getElementById( 'opt_2' );
opt.selected = true;
})();">Select Two</a>` ? Obviously you'd need to update to your use case